# my sql server does not have a maintenance plan wizard

Tags: sql-server

I am a beginner in the sql server and wanted to create a maintenance plan through the wizard, but my database does not contain it. I have the adminsys rule and XPs agent enabled.

[image]

Comment: Could you please check the following MS-article   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/maintenance-plans/use-the-maintenance-plan-wizard?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: but the article refers to the wizard, and in my database it does not contain it

Comment: Please take a look on the following quotation "To create or manage maintenance plans, you must be a member of the sysadmin fixed server role. Object Explorer only displays the Maintenance Plans node for users who are members of the sysadmin fixed server role."

Comment: but i am sysadmin

Comment: It is perfect. I hope, you have implemented  "Prerequisites You must enable Agent XPs Server Configuration Option." and restarted SSMS to be sure

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you running, and what version of SSMS are you using?

Comment: You said you're a member of the `sysadmin` role - but are you using Windows Authentication or SQL Server Authentication? You *may* need to run SSMS Elevated ("Run as Administrator").